# R S4 best practice: slot with "vector of S4 objects"

Tags: r, r-s4, slot

How does one correctly do the following:

I have a class SpectraSet with slots parentSpectrum, childSpectra, name (to keep it simple)

name is character()

parentSpectrum should contain one object of class ParentSpec (so it is of type ParentSpec)

childSpectra should contain n objects of class ChildSpec. However I can't make it of type ChildSpec because vectors can only contain atomic types. What is best practice in this case? I can make it a list() and type check in the validity check, but is there anything better?

Answer (score 0):

Here are [related anaswers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A547331+SimpleList) I've provided in the past.

It's usually better to re-think the class design so ChildSpec is intrinsically a vector -- minimally, supports length() and subsetting [, [[. Your problem above then goes away, the design is consistent with R's vectorized orientation, and likely common operations are efficient.

An alternative to implementing your own type-checked list (which is really the other alternative) is to re-use the infrastructure from [Biocdonductor](http://bioconductor.org)'s [S4Vectors](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/S4Vectors.html) class

```
.X = setClass("X", representation(x="numeric"))
.XList = setClass("XList", contains="SimpleList",
    prototype=prototype(elementType="X"))
```

And in action

```
> xl = .XList(listData=list(.X(x=1), .X(x=2)))
> xl
XList of length 2
> xl[[2]]
An object of class "X"
Slot "x":
[1] 2
```

Comment: Hm - not sure whether that approach (thinking of ChildSpectra instead of ChildSpectrum) is possible in my case, since I derive ChildSpec from an existing Spectrum class in another package (MSnbase Spectrum2). Also, every spectrum is already an object of multiple n-length vectors (that can be exported as a dataframe) plus additional 1-length properties. I still have to wrap my head around this.